# MFC Edit control - WM_DROPFILES message register for drag and drop

Tags: mfc, textbox, drag-and-drop, editcontrol

According to [this article](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1737/How-to-Accept-Drag-and-Drop-Files-from-Windows-Explorer.html), to allow Drop Only on the Target, we have to

> Use SubclassDlgItem() to re-route that one message to the dialog object so that all of the handling can be done there.

Mr. DanRollins (the author of the article) also provides an example

```
class CEditDropNotif : public CEdit
{
    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg) {
        if ( pMsg->message == WM_DROPFILES ) {
            GetParent()->SendMessage(WM_DROPFILES, pMsg->wParam, pMsg->lParam);
            return TRUE; // eat it
        }
        return FALSE; // allow default processing
    }
};
BOOL CMyDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
 ...
    static CEditDropNotif cEd;  // must persist (usually a dlg member)
    cEd.SubclassDlgItem( IDC_EDIT1, this );
    ::DragAcceptFiles( cEd.m_hWnd, true );  // the editbox, not the dialog
 ...
```

But I don't understand why Edit control (CEdit) has the **Accept Files** in the properties window (Visual Studio Resource view), but can't register the message WM_DROPFILES for itself without having to create an inherited class (or it can but I haven't known yet).

I see that we can register the click message for button by the following code

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CSimpleDlg, CDialogEx)
...
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_01, &CSimpleDlg::OnBnClickedBtn01)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Is there a way I can do similar for drag drop event, like

```
ON_DRAW_DROP(IDC_TXT_01, &CSimpleDlg::OnDragDrop01)//Is exist?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: Nope.
**ON_BN_CLICKED** macro maps a member function that handles **BN_CLICKED** notification sent via **WM_COMMAND** message. The notifications are sent to control's parent (although MFC has also a "reflection" mechanism that forwards the notifications to controls). 
**WM_DROPFILES** is a general Windows message, not a notification so that's it: if you want to handle it then you have to derive from **CEdit**.

See also:

- [Message Categories](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/message-categories)
- [Message Reflection for Windows Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/tn062-message-reflection-for-windows-controls)